# Research question thesis

Tags: programming

I am now in high school and have to do research. But I am not sure which research question to choose. I would like to talk about programming languages and therefore something within computer science. Can someone give me some examples of research questions where you don't need a lot of prior knowledge? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Say some more about context. Why do you "have to" do this? Is it an assignment, or just an interest? What sorts of things about programming languages interest you? What sorts of background do you bring to the task?

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for your response! It is an assignment. Everything about programming languages is interesting to me, but not very specific, difficult subjects. I do not have a programming background.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to give you an answer directly, let me direct you to a web site that is full of ideas, not for research, but for how programming and programmers can affect things. [Paul Graham](http://paulgraham.com/articles.html) is a computer scientist, mostly associated with the Lisp family of languages and has done some very interesting things with Common Lisp.

But his essays are just ideas that are interesting, if nothing else. Reading them is likely to give you ideas as well.

Poking around in them might give you some ideas. But, you might also want to think about not making your research too narrow. Not just programming or programming languages, or even just CS, but how it all relates to the wider world and the other things you've been studying.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a study on say:

1. Evolution of programming languages.
2. How software development has driven hardware development e.g. how increasing size of code drives requirements for larger storage.
3. Since it's a high school research, you could study how computers have changed  our lives or the way we use time in a day
4. You may take any programming language and study how it has evolved, the founder(s), versions,  it's major principles, with sample code etc. C++ will be most interesting in this regard IMHO, cos it has evolved and is still evolving significantly from its beginnings in the 1980s. 
   Hope these get you thinking of something

Comment: Thank you very much!!